# Build LibreOffice Uno libraries for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, libreoffice, openoffice.org, uno

I want to use uno libraries to disable some of the menu options in Libreoffice document.

1. Os Using: Linux

   > uname -a
   >   Linux  #1 SMP Tue Feb 4 23:02:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
   >   86_64 GNU/Linux
2. Python version : Python 3.6.8
3. libreoffice version - LibreOffice 5.3.6.1 30(Build:1)

I am not able to do "import uno" or "import pyuno" in python 3. However both commands are working properly in Python2

Error I am getting in python 3:

```
    >>> import pyuno
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_pyuno)
    >>> import uno
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uno'
```

Some of the more research which I have done

```
    (/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program)-1037> objdump -t -T -r -R pyuno.so | grep initpyuno
    0000000000000a90 g    DF .text  0000000000000117  Base        initpyuno
```

I think my libreoffice is built against Python 2.x . But I wasnt able to find any solution how to  build it against python3.x
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answers are likely to be different depending on the flavor of Linux, so be sure to edit the question to give your specific OS name and version (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for example). Have you checked if the appropriate package such as `libreoffice-script-provider-python` is installed? Also, you may get better answers asking on the Unix & Linux SE site.

Comment: How to check for libreoffice-script-provider-python package?

Comment: Read through [libreoffice-script-provider-python](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=libreoffice-script-provider-python)

Comment: @stovfl :it have

`(/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/Scripts/python)-997> ls

Capitalise.py Capitalise.pyo HelloWorld.pyc pythonSamples Capitalise.pyc HelloWorld.py HelloWorld.pyo`